# How to implement prism for GADT?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, gadt

I have GADT data type like this:

```
data TValue = TInt | TBool

data Value (t :: TValue) where
    I :: Int  -> Value 'TInt
    B :: Bool -> Value 'TBool
```

And I want to have prisms for pattern matching on this data type. I'm using data prism approach for simplicity. So previously I had something like this:

```
data ValuePrism (tag :: TValue) a = ValuePrism
    { matchValue :: forall t . Value t -> Maybe a
    , buildValue :: a -> Value tag
    }

boolPrism :: ValuePrism 'TBool Bool
boolPrism = ValuePrism matchBool B
  where
    matchBool :: Value t -> Maybe Bool
    matchBool (B b) = Just b
    matchBool _     = Nothing
```

I want to fit this use case into prisms interface. I can specify type in the following way:

```
data Prism s t a b = Prism
    { preview :: s -> Either t a
    , review  :: b -> t
    }

type ValuePrism (tag :: TValue) a = 
    forall t . Prism (Value t) (Value tag) a a
```

But I'm unable to write function which creates `ValuePrism` according to old interface:

```
mkValuePrism :: (forall t . Value t -> Maybe a)
             -> (a -> Value tag)
             -> ValuePrism tag a
mkValuePrism = =<< (ツ) >>=
```

Is there some way to create prism for GADT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to change your second definition of `ValuePrism`.

Your first `ValuePrism 'TBool Bool` does not contain a function of type `Bool -> Value 'TInt`, but your second `ValuePrism 'TBool Bool` does (by specializing the `forall`'d `t` to `'TInt` and calling `review`). Such a function can be cooked up from scratch, but it will necessarily be what I would call "unreasonable". You could define

```
type ValuePrism tag a = Prism (Value tag) (Value tag) a a
```

instead; you will then find the translation much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my use case I have an existential wrapper around `Value t`, this one: `data AnyValue = forall t . AnyValue (Value t)`. Will I be able to extract from this type using my prism?

Comment: @Shersh Sure, it should be quite easy to write a term of type e.g. `Prism AnyValue AnyValue Bool Bool`. For example, `Prism (\s -> case s of AnyValue (B b) -> Right b; _ -> Left s) (AnyValue . B)` will do.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your suggestions! I've implemented discussed approach in this PR if you're interested: https://github.com/kowainik/tomland/pull/65